# PHP Password_Hash generating different hashes for static password

Tags: php, encryption

The title is self explanatory. The following hashes are generated for the pass 'hi'. As you can see each hash is different than the last. Not sure how this is possible for a 1 way encryption algo. Please help

1. $2y$10$W3ZkFyZl/72RZn4S.98y/OnqA/efNqoY4blB2AHimJlgDANYA9qKy
2. $2y$10$juwL/E/Z9vh5Hj6An/.nauzeFw4vhXaQSR7g7eP3.gZ9JLsREXNi6
3. $2y$10$11GUeaQ5rhJ21wHIUzAt5OM4Ol0qJ4pV5ZB//OiK1GuJYMg7o1PAu

Comment: It generates a different salt each time, so the resultant hash is also different.

Comment: Did you check https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php if all three will validate to TRUE  or is this just a background question on encryption mechanisms of  https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So for implementing the following function into a 'log in' portal would you store the first hash generated as the password? Or how will you know which hash to use such that the password will generate it each time? 1. user enters password. 2. Password_hash user pass. 3. Compare user pass hash to db hash. Will these not be different each time?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig We currently use the password_verify function however it will only work on some passwords. For example we had users that were unable to log into the website for hashes with several special characters. I am having a hard time explaining and reasoning what is happening in the back end.

Comment: @Stonen2 You must use [`password_verify($password_from_login, $hash_from_database)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to test the password. You store the hash from `password_hash()` in the database, use `password_verify()` to compare it.

Comment: One initial call to `password_hash()` is all you ever need - store that value and you will not call `password_hash()` again unless you reset the password.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you!!

Comment: If you're seeing failures on password_verify(), I'd start by checking two things: 1) Make sure your database field is big enough to hold these long hash strings, and 2) Make sure the code that gets run before saving the hash doesn't strip any characters that the user typed.

Comment: FTR, it's supposed to work like this. a) It protects against using precomputed hashes to find passwords (google "rainbow tables"). b) It makes it impossible to tell if two users use the same password.

Answer (score -1):

Are your database fields large enough?  If you cut the hash it will result in invalid  verifications.   The hashes do not have the same length! Not even for the same password.

Possibly you are modifying (only some) hashes  upon inserting it into the database or retrieving from the database: ??? use prepared statements to insert it into the db.

Do not use any sanitation on the hash!

see short example 10 times the pw is the same- the HASH is different and 10 times the verify is OK :-)

```
<?php


for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
{
$pw = "öä?hgu.+?w55&rg:9/stf";

echo $pw_hash= password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

echo "<br>";
echo password_verify($pw, $pw_hash)? "passwort ok": "passwort falsch";
echo"<p> next iteration: <br>";
}
```